# Replace chars in multiple files in multiple directories

Tags: files, rename

On my Qnap I'm trying to replace "xyz" in filenames to "abc" in files in multiple directories. Being a unix/linux newbie, i tried the following command:

```
for f in *xyz*; do mv -i "$f" "${f//xyz/abc}"; done
```

This works perfect for the files in a directory, but does not work for files in the sub-directories. How can I change the above to also make it work for files in the subdirectories ?

Comment: What shell do you use? In bash you could use `globstar`.

Comment: I use MacOs terminal to SSH into my Qnap

Comment: OK, I asked what shell do you use on your Qnap? If you're not sure post output of `echo $SHELL` or press Control-x Control-v and check if something like `GNU bash, version 4.3.46(1)-release (x86_64-slackware-linux-gnu)` shows up on the screen.

Comment: exciting `echo $SHELL` gives me: /bin/sh

Comment: ctrl-x ctrl v gives me: GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-QNAP-linux-gnu)

Comment: I posted an answer but removed it since `globstar` was added only in Bash 4.0. Can you post output of `shopt  | grep globstar`?

Comment: no result, shopt gives a list with on/off but lobster is not on there

Comment: OK, I posted a new answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments OP uses `bash` shell on their QNAP
device but since it's Bash 3 globstar cannot be used because in was
added in Bash 4.0.  In that case `find` is one of the possible
solutions.

Example:

First, create an example directory structure and create *xyz* files:

```
$ mkdir -p 1/2/3
$ touch  a_xyz_a 1/2/b_xyz_b 1/2/3/c_xyz_c
```

Now run `find` + `mv`:

```
$ find . -name "*xyz*" -exec sh -c 'echo mv -i "$1" "${1//xyz/abc}";' sh {} \;
mv -i ./a_xyz_a ./a_abc_a
mv -i ./1/2/3/c_xyz_c ./1/2/3/c_abc_c
mv -i ./1/2/b_xyz_b ./1/2/b_abc_b
```

Remove `echo` to actually execute `mv`.

Comment: Thank you for all the efforts, the above line gives me: -sh: $: command not found

Comment: Do not copy the initial `$`, it's here to represent prompt.

Comment: euhm.. i'm so glad i put newbie in my nick :)

Comment: Yes, it's good :) Does it work for you?

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you very much

Comment: @Qnap_Newbie: ok, you can now mark this answer as accepted to let other users know that your problem is solved. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers